# SYMFONY Custom Constraint in FORM, `validate()` from `class ****validator extends ConstraintValidator`, not triggered thru buildForm() implementation

Tags: forms, symfony-forms, symfony

I am having trouble with a custom constraint I designed in SYMFONY, I made it work and then it stopped working, and I am trying to figure out what I am doing wrong.

About the code here is a question I posted few days ago with my full code regarding my custom constraint: [My custom constraint code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37479328/symfony-custom-constraint-pass-variable-to-a-custom-constraint-how-constrai)

I will copy the part of code that leads this new question.

I put some `dump()` to see what was working in my `__construct()` function of the class extending Constraint:

```
/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class CheckValueAlreadyInDB extends Constraint{
public $message;
public $fieldToSearch;
public $tableToSearch;
public $idToCheck;
public $idToCheckFieldName;

public function __construct($options){
    dump($options);
    if(count($options)>0){
        $this->idToCheck = $options['idToCheck'];
        $this->idToCheckFieldName = $options['idToCheckFieldName'];
        $this->fieldToSearch = $options['fieldToSearch'];
        $this->tableToSearch = $options['tableToSearch'];
        $this->message = $options['message'];
    }
}

public function validatedBy()
{
    dump('validatedBy() starts');
     return 'validator_check_value_already_in_db';
}
}
```

And, the ConstraintValidator extended class linked to it:

```
class CheckValueAlreadyInDBValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    private $con;

    public function __construct($con){
        $this->con = $con;
    }

    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
       dump('validate starts');
        ////My stuff to get a record from the DB////
        $sel = new PdoSelect($this->con);
        $search = $sel->returnRecordsInTableForSpecificKey([$constraint->fieldToSearch],[$value],  $constraint->tableToSearch,false);
       //////////////////////////////////////////////

        $sameId = false;
        if($constraint->idToCheck!==null){
            $idToCheckInRetrieveRecord = $search->{$constraint->idToCheckFieldName};            
            $sameId = ($idToCheckInRetrieveRecord==$constraint->idToCheck)?true:false;
        }

        if($search!=null&&!$sameId){
            $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
                ->setParameter('%string%', $value)
                ->addViolation();
        }
    }
}
```

And in the form design:

```
class MyEntityType extends AbstractType {     
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
      {

    ....
        $builder->add('myValue',****Type::class,array(
          'constraints' => array(
              new CheckValueAlreadyInDB(array(
                'idToCheck'=>$options['data']->getId(),
                'idToCheckFieldName'=>'id',
                'fieldToSearch'=>'my_value',
                'tableToSearch'=>'my_table',
                'message' => "value_already_exists_in_db"))
            )
          ));

    ...
    }
}
```

When I submit the form, it doesn't go correctly because it is not triggering the constraint. I can see thru the SYMFONY _profiler that the `dump($options)` in `__construct()`, of class CheckValueAlreadyInDB, works but I don't see the `dump('validatedBy() starts')` from the class CheckValueAlreadyInDB and neither the `dump('validate starts')` from the class CheckValueAlreadyInDBValidator.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong or have any hint about where I should investigate?

**Additional info about the code:**

MyEntity class:

```
class MyEntity{


        /**
        * @MyBundleAssert\CheckValueAlreadyInDB(
        *     message = "already_exists_in_db",
        *     fieldToSearch = "my_value",
        *     tableToSearch = "my_table"
        *)
        */
        private myValue;

    }
```

And my service:

```
validator.unique.check_value_already_in_db:
    class: MyBundle\Form\CustomConstraints\CheckValueAlreadyInDBValidator
    arguments: ['@doctrine.dbal.default_connection']
    tags:
        - { name: validator.constraint_validator, alias: validator_check_value_already_in_db }
```

Comment: can you post the entity that you wish to validate? I think constraints are linked to entity

Comment: I edited the question with the entity that I use at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

My mistake was to try to use `constraints` in `class MyEntityType extends AbstractType`:

```
   $builder->add('myValue',****Type::class,array(
      'constraints' => array(
          new CheckValueAlreadyInDB(array(
            'idToCheck'=>$options['data']->getId(),
            'idToCheckFieldName'=>'id',
            'fieldToSearch'=>'my_value',
            'tableToSearch'=>'my_table',
            'message' => "value_already_exists_in_db"))
        )
      ));
```

**DON'T USE IT HERE**

Have a look at [class-constraint-validator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html#class-constraint-validator) section in the doc.

**Implement the `ConstraintValidator` extended class above the class of the Entity where the validator has to execute its check and not above one attribute of the Entity class. That way one can have access to other attributes of the entity and use it as conditionals in the `ConstraintValidator` extended class.**